# cakephp cant do attribute add

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

```
    echo '<div class="myclass">';
    echo $form->input('Car Model:',array('id'=>'carmodels', 'name'=>'carmodels', 'options' => $year, 'label'=>false, 'div'=>false));
    echo '</div>'

<div class="myclass">
<select name="carmodels" id="carmodels">
<option value="1995">Jaq</option>
<option value="1996">Reliant</option>
<option value="1997">Toyota</option>
</select></div>
```

But now I need to add an attribute to the option called body. so that it shows

```
<div class="myclass">
<select name="carmodels" id="carmodels">
<option value="1995" body="4door">Jaq</option>
<option value="1996" body="2door">Reliant</option>
<option value="1997" body="4 door">Toyota</option>
</select></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do what you wish to do using $form->input() or $form->select().  The options array passed to either function will only accept a simple name => value array.

Not sure why you're doing this as it's not even valid HTML, but if you really want the output above, just generate the option tags with a for loop.

Comment: Note that data-body="..." would be valid HTML5, and is automatically parsed as metadata by recent versions of jQuery. Not that anyone mentioned jQuery :)

Comment: Guess I sound like someone who hasn't work with html5 yet haha. Noted!

Comment: @Amir If you're going to make statements like that, please at least provide an rationale as to why.

Answer (score 2):

it is possible this way:

```
$options = array(
    ...
    array('name' => 'United states', 'value' => 'USA', 'title' => 'the title that you want'),
    array('name' => 'USA', 'value' => 'USA', 'title' => 'the other title that you want'),
 );

 echo $this->Form->input('test', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$options));
```

take a look at this link for some cool stuff about the cakephp input and select:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/03/01/some-new-crazy-cakephp-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = array(
                 1 => 'One', 
                 2 => array('name' => 'Two', 'value' => 2,  'class' => 'extra'), 
                 3 => 'Three',
                 6 => array('name' => 'Six', 'value' => 6, "data-icon"=>"fa-arrow-circle-o-right")
);

echo $this->Form->input('my_option_id',array('type' =>'select', 'options'=>$options));
```

HTML=>

```
<select name="data[my_option_id]" id="my_option_id">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" class="extra">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="6" data-icon="fa-arrow-circle-o-right" >Six</option>
</select>
```

[CakePHP data-icon in select dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386787/cakephp-data-icon-in-select-dropdown/23387273#23387273)

Answer (score -1):

$options = array( 1995 => 'Jaq', 1996 => 'Reliant', 1996 => 'Toyota' );
echo $form->select( 'title',$options,null, array('class' => 'ddlSortModule'),false );