# CakePHP data-icon in select dropdown

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

Using CakePHP (2.3), is there a way to easily add extra parameters to the option element of a select box?

When creating a select dropdown in a template using the following code :

```
echo $this->Form->input('icon_id', array(
  'label' => 'Icon',
  'empty' => ' ',
  'class' => 'selectbox'
));
```

The following HTML is output (which is correct) :

```
<div class="input select">
  <select name="data[Link][icon_id]" class="selectbox" id="LinkIconId">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="16">fa-adjust</option>
    <option value="76">fa-anchor</option>
    <option value="135">fa-archive</option>
    <option value="6">fa-arrow-cicle-o-right</option>
    <option value="10">fa-arrow-circle-o-left</option>
...
```

My question is, can I programmatically add attributes to the option tag like, and specifically, I'd like to add the data-icon attribute, with the value being the same as the option text?  For Example :

```
    <option value="6" data-icon="fa-arrow-circle-o-right">fa-arrow-cicle-o-right</option>
```

I have a feeling I might need to write a helper to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$options = array(
                 1 => 'One', 
                 2 => array('name' => 'Two', 'value' => 2,  'class' => 'extra'), 
                 3 => 'Three',
                 6 => array('name' => 'Six', 'value' => 6, "data-icon"=>"fa-arrow-circle-o-right")
);

echo $this->Form->input('my_option_id',array('type' =>'select', 'options'=>$options));
```

HTML=>

```
<select name="data[my_option_id]" id="my_option_id">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" class="extra">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="6" data-icon="fa-arrow-circle-o-right" >Six</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thats a great idea. So I have done the following.  In my controller I changed the way the ifind works to this:  $icons = Hash::map($this->Link->Icon->find('list', array('order' => array('Icon.name' => 'ASC'))), '', function($newArr) {
   return(array('name'=>$newArr,'data-icon'=>'fa '.$newArr));
    });  But i have no way of getting the value of the icon_id using this hash map so that i can set 'value'=>'...'

Comment: maybe...because you are doing it on find list. you should get it on find all. i have to see how your table and data looks like

Comment: I've fixed it, i build my own array after extraction from the database (foreach $icons as $key=>$value)... and then pass that to the view which now gives me data-icon attribute!  Thanks for your help.